# How to open same animation with two same box colliders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a level in a game where when you get in a box collider, a portal opens, and when you leave it, it closes. Both portals need to open when I enter in box collider 1, and both need to close when i leave it. This also needs to happen when I enter in a box collider 2 of the second portal. I have a script for  box collider 1 and I apply it to box collider 2. It checks if the player is in a collider. I have an animator bool which directly takes variable from box collider script to check in range. I use  that bool for animation. However, that animator bool doesen't work for box collider 2. Variable for box collider works, but not animator bool. Is there a way to connect that second one, or do i need to make a new script for that box collider?

**Box Collider Code:**

```
    public bool inRange;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            inRange = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            inRange = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

**Portal Script Code:**

```
public class Portal : MonoBehaviour {

    private Animator anim;

    private bool inPortalRange;

    public GameObject portalBorder;

    void Start ()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        OpenPortal();
        UpdateAnimation();
    }

    private void UpdateAnimation()
    {
        anim.SetBool("inPortalRange", inPortalRange);
    }

    private void OpenPortal()
    {
        PortalBorder poborder = portalBorder.GetComponent<PortalBorder>();
        inPortalRange = poborder.inRange;
    }
}
```

**A picture of a situation:**

[image: Portals]

Comment: Please don't add tags that are irrelevant to the question. This questions is not related to the C language in any way, so that tag should not have been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all you should not use `GetComponent` every frame. Either like the `anim` you should rather store it right away. Or you could simply make `portalBorder` of type `PortalBorder` then the according reference is set automatically when referencing it via the Inspector.
- Then yes currently you are only updating one of the animators. In order to control them both you have to connect them somehow.

I would do something like this

```
public class Portal : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Animator anim;
    private bool inPortalRange;
    // Public read-only access
    public bool InPortalRange => inPortalRange;

    // Reference each other via the Inspector in both portals
    public Portal OtherPortal;

    // Give this directly the according type so you don't need GetComponent at all
    public PortalBorder portalBorder;

    // I would recommend to do things always as early as possible
    // Awake is executed before Start
    private void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        OpenPortal();
        UpdateAnimation();
    }

    private void UpdateAnimation()
    {
        // Here now use the range of either this or the other portal
        anim.SetBool("inPortalRange", InPortalRange || OtherPortal.inPortalRange );
    }

    private void OpenPortal()
    {
        inPortalRange = portalBorder.inRange;
    }
}
```

---

However instead of making it a polling call in `Update` I would actually rather use an event driven approach:

```
public class PortalBorder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent OnEnteredPortalRange;
    public UnityEvent OnLeftPortalRange;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            OnEnteredPortalRange.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            OnEnteredPortalRange.Invoke();
        }
    } 
}
```

Now your script has to [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) (just like the `onClick` of buttons) where you can add callbacks either via the inspector or using code

```
public class Portal : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Animator anim;
    private bool inPortalRange;
    // Public read-only access
    public bool InPortalRange => inPortalRange;

    // Reference each other via the Inspector in both portals
    public Portal OtherPortal;

    // Give this directly the according type so you don't need GetComponent at all
    public PortalBorder portalBorder;

    // I would recommend to do things always as early as possible
    // Awake is executed before Start
    private void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        // Instead of checking a bool in Update simply
        // wait until the according events get invoked
        portalBorder.OnEnteredPortalRange.AddListener(EnablePortal);
        portalBorder.OnLeftPortalRange.AddListener(DisablePortal);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // always make sure to remove callbacks when not needed anymore
        // in roder to avoid NullReferenceExceptions
        portalBorder.OnEnteredPortalRange.RemoveListener(EnablePortal);
        portalBorder.OnLeftPortalRange.RemoveListener(DisablePortal);
    }

    public void EnablePortal()
    {
        anim.SetBool("inPortalRange", true);
        OtherPortal.anim.SetBool("inPortalRange", true);
    }

    public void DisablePortal()
    {
        anim.SetBool("inPortalRange", false);
        OtherPortal.anim.SetBool("inPortalRange", false);
    }
}
```